# get n leftBits of binary in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Got function getLeftBits(int n,int num) and I need to return num bits from left for example:

```
getLeftBits(7,31) --> 3  
getLeftBits(-1,2) --> 3
```

I handle it easy for every n>0: `n >> (32 - num)`
but when n<0 got some problems.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen? Is `n` an `int` or `unsigned int`? With `int`, you'll get a sign extend fill on the left, but with `unsigned int` you'll get zero filled. Based on your 2nd example, you probably want the 1st arg to be unsigned, so: `unsigned int getLeftBits(unsigned int n,int num) { return n >> (32 - num); }`. Also, what if `num` is zero (you'll always get the same result, regardless of the value of `n`)? Or, if `num` is negative, what do you _want_ to happen?

Comment: @CraigEstey: it is implementation defined whether *you'll get a sign extend fill on the left* or not or something else. **C17 6.5.7 Bitwise Shift Operators** *The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1`/2^`E2`. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well you want to see the n leftmost bits of the binary representation of the number.

Most of the implementations will use arithmetic right shift not the logical right shift. You need to cast the number to unsigned integer to prevent this behaviour. It does not matter when you shift unsigned numbers, but it matters when you shift the signed number.

[image]

```
unsigned getLeftBits(int n, int num)
{
    return n >> (32 - num);
}

unsigned getLeftBits1(int n, int num)
{
    return (unsigned)n >> (32 - num);
}

getLeftBits:
        mov     ecx, 32
        mov     eax, edi
        sub     ecx, esi
        sar     eax, cl              <-------here
        ret
getLeftBits1:
        mov     ecx, 32
        mov     eax, edi
        sub     ecx, esi
        shr     eax, cl              <-------here            
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/JuY_z4